# Need help on constructing this jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a bunch of div tags in my html page. Now I need to write a jQuery to calculate the grid's value. In the below example I will be using grid0 as the base id and I want the count in that series which is 1 here.

```
<div id="grid00">0</div>
<div id="grid01">0</div>
<div id="grid02">0</div>
<div id="grid03">1</div>
<div id="grid04">0</div>
<div id="grid05">0</div>
```

In another example given below I will be using id's starting with grid1 and the total value is 6. Please guide me!

```
<div id="grid10">5</div>
<div id="grid11">0</div>
<div id="grid12">0</div>
<div id="grid13">1</div>
<div id="grid14">0</div>
<div id="grid15">0</div>
```

I tried this `jQuery("div[id^='grid0']")`. But this is giving me all the elements. But I need the count using the value inside them.

Thanks!

Comment: any reason you can't add a class to all the elements to simplify the selectors?

Comment: @zzzzBov : this is just an example. My implementation is a bit complex.. I can't simply using classes..

Comment: if your implementation of an HTML page is too complicated to add classes, IMHO you're doing it wrong. [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by selecting the divs with the [starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and loop through the results and tally up the text values casted to integers.

---

```
function GetSum(prefix) {
    var sum = 0;
    $("div[id^='" + prefix + "']").each(function(){
        sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    return sum;
}

var grid0Total = GetSum("grid0");
var grid1Total = GetSum("grid1");
```

---

Or if you wanted to take it a step further with a jQuery function:

```
jQuery.extend({
    gridSum: function(prefix) { 
        var sum = 0;
        if(!!prefix) { 
            $("div[id^='" + prefix + "']").each(function(){
                sum += parseInt($(this).text());
            });
        }
        return sum;
    }
});
```

then you could write:

```
var grid0Total = jQuery.gridSum("grid0");
var grid1Total = jQuery.gridSum("grid1");
```

---

You could also use the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function like so:

```
var sum = 0;
$("div[id^='" + prefix + "']").map(function(){
    return sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
return sum;
```

---

See them all in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/FpmFW/1/

Comment: Wow, you are way faster. Still, fun to use the ^= selector for something :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
function total(idPrefix) {
    var total = 0;
    $('div[id^="' + idPrefix + '"]').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    return total;
}

var grid0total = total('grid0'),
    grid1total = total('grid1');
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Au8Fr/

Answer (score 1):

I'd give all grid divs one commmon class. Something like this:

```
<div class="grid" id="myGrids">
<div class="grid" id="grid10">5</div>
<div class="grid" id="grid11">0</div>
<div class="grid" id="grid12">0</div>
<div class="grid" id="grid13">1</div>
<div class="grid" id="grid14">0</div>
<div class="grid" id="grid15">0</div>
</div>
```

Now you can easily count their values:

```
var count=0;
$(".grid").each(function(){
 count+=parseInt($(this).text())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all of your `grid0X` `divs` like this:

```
var countOnes = 0;
$('div[id^=grid0]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "1") {
        ++countOnes;
    }
});
```

That finds all `div` elements whose ID *starts with* `grid0` (so, `grid00`, `grid01`, etc.). The loop counts how many of them contain just the text "1", which is what I *think* you were after in your question; if not, the loop logic is easily manipulated.

Similarly, for `grid1X`, just change the selector to use `1` instead of `0`.

Alternately, though, if these divs are in some kind of container, you could use a selector to find the container and then loop through its children, e.g.:

HTML:

```
<div id="grid0">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>0</div>
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>0</div>
    <div>0</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#grid0 > div").each(...);
```

...and avoid having all those IDs.